Move all Items found by Restrict() method
Consider the following Outlook VBA code:
Sub Macro1() 'Move e-mail messages from "Inbox" folder to "New Applications"
  Dim olMapi As NameSpace
  Dim olStore As Outlook.Store
  Dim olRootFldr As Outlook.Folder
  Dim olFldrInbox As Outlook.Folder
  Dim olFldrSbmtd As Outlook.Folder
  Dim dateMin As Date, dateMax As Date
  Dim sFilterDmin As String
  Dim sFilterDmax As String
  Dim olItm As Object
  Dim olEmls As Outlook.Items
  Dim olEml As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim nApplications as Integer

  Set olMapi = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set olStore = olMapi.Stores("Application Processing Department")
  Set olRootFldr = olStore.GetRootFolder
  Set olFldrInbox = olRootFldr.Folders("Inbox")
  Set olFldrSbmtd = olRootFldr.Folders("Submitted Applications")
  dateMax = Date - 5
  dateMin = dateMax - 2
  sFilterDmin = "[ReceivedTime]>='" & Format(dateMin, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'"
  sFilterDmax = "[ReceivedTime]<='" & Format(dateMax, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'"
  Set olEmls = olFldrInbox.Items.Restrict(sFilterDmin)
  If olEmls Is Nothing Then MsgBox "!olEmls1": Exit Sub
  Set olEmls = olEmls.Restrict(sFilterDmax)
  If olEmls Is Nothing Then MsgBox "!olEmls2": Exit Sub
  
  'MsgBox "olEmls.Count=" & olEmls.Count

  nApplications = 0  
  For Each olItm In olEmls
    If TypeOf olItm Is Outlook.MailItem Then
      Set olEml = olItm
      If Not olEml Is Nothing Then
        If Left(UCase(olEml.Subject), 16) = "APPLICATION FOR " Then
          olEml.Move olFldrSbmtd.Folders("New Applications")
          nApplications = nApplications + 1
        End If
        Set olEml = Nothing
      End If
    End If
    DoEvents
  Next olItm
  MsgBox "moved nApplications=" & nApplications
  
End Sub

When I have one message in the Inbox with Subject that starts with "New Application for ..." then MsgBox shows "moved nApplications=1" and that message gets moved to the "New Applications" folder as expected.
If there are two messages then MsgBox still shows "moved nApplications=1" and I have to run this macro again to move the second message.
What should be changed in my code above to force Items.Restrict() method to include both/all messages satisfying the given criteria? Btw, if there are 10 messages in the Inbox then the first run of macro may show "moved nApplications=3" (sometimes "moved nApplications=4"); second invocation may show "moved nApplications=2", but it never shows the expected result.

That is because you are using a For Each loop and you are changing the collection that you are iterating over. Use a down for loop
for i= olEmls.Count to 1 step -1
  set olItm = olEmls(i)


your are absolutely right (sorry for the late reply).
